# source code of web page not available using urllib.urlopen()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am trying to get video links from `'https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind'`. When I do inspect elements, it displays me the source html code for each videos. In source code retrieved using

```
urllib2.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind").read()
```

It does not display html source for videos. Is there any otherway to do this?

```
<a href="/watch?v=dCdvyFkctOo" alt="Flipkart Wish Chain">
        <img src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/dCdvyFkctOo/hqdefault.jpg" alt="Flipkart Wish Chain">
      </a>
```

This simple code appears when we inspect elements from browser, but not in source code retrived by `urllib`

Comment: Can you add a part of the code you use to access YouTube page?

Comment: Yup. You just connected a socket to the webpage but didn't read from it.

Comment: @AdityaJoshi: already did it, missed to mention read() in question, updated.

Answer (score 1):

works for me...

```
import urllib2
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

IMO I'd use `requests` instead of `urllib` - it's a bit easier to use:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
```

**Edit**

This will get you a list of all `<a></a>` tags with hyperlinks as per your edit. I use the library [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the html:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = [tag for tag in soup.findAll('a') if tag.has_attr('href')]
```

Comment: thanks, could you see `/watch?v=dCdvyFkctOo` and other source code as i described in question in source code?

Answer (score 1):

To view the source code you need use `read` method
If you just use open it gives you something like this.

```
In [12]: urllib2.urlopen('https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind')
Out[12]: <addinfourl at 3054207052L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0xb60a6f2c>>
```

To see the source use `read`

```
urllib2.urlopen('https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard#loc0=ind').read()
```

Comment: @nlper May be you need to use Mechanize module for this

Comment: any link or example for Mechanize module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852041/how-to-download-youtube-videos-using-a-python-script

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you compare the source code between Python code and Web browser, dont do it through Insect Element, right click on the webpage and click view source, then you will find the actual source. Inspect Element displays the aggregated source code returned by as many network requests created as well as javascript code being executed.

Keep Developer Console open before opening the webpage, stay on Network tab and make sure that 'Preserve Log' is open for Chrome or 'Persist' for Firebug in Firefox, then you will see all the network requests made.

Comment: Also, try sending the *User-Agent* string in headers. That is a very important part. Requests library is much easier to use in such case. I will post an example.

Comment: thanks, but code which I can see in inspect elements does not appear in page source. I am expecting video urls, which are there on page, but does not appear when I get source page?

Comment: Thats what I meant. That source is same as what you receive via Python code. So look at the Network tab as I explained in my answer and try to see what all requests have been made.

Comment: thanks again, but network tab appears emtry even after preserver tab ticked

Comment: Actually, you are not being able to use it properly. Are you using Chrome? Also, load the web page only after you have Network tab open and Preserve Log clicked.

Answer (score 0):

we also need to decode the data to utf-8.
here is the code:

just use 
response.decode('utf-8')
print(response)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.